# Google Maps Android API v2 and Eclipse, unable to run

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am new in Google Map and try to do something about it. I follow a link and create a project to do testing. After run the project and get a list of errors, below is the error i get in my project:

```
01-23 19:03:12.187: D/AndroidRuntime(30602): Shutting down VM
01-23 19:03:12.187: W/dalvikvm(30602): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40018578)
01-23 19:03:12.210: E/AndroidRuntime(30602): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-23 19:03:12.210: E/AndroidRuntime(30602): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.googlemapstest/com.example.googlemapstest.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class fragment
01-23 19:03:12.210: E/AndroidRuntime(30602):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1651)
01-23 19:03:12.210: E/AndroidRuntime(30602):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
01-23 19:03:12.210: E/AndroidRuntime(30602):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
01-23 19:03:12.210: E/AndroidRuntime(30602):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
01-23 19:03:12.210: E/AndroidRuntime(30602):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-23 19:03:12.210: E/AndroidRuntime(30602):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
01-23 19:03:12.210: E/AndroidRuntime(30602):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
01-23 19:03:12.210: E/AndroidRuntime(30602):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-23 19:03:12.210: E/AndroidRuntime(30602):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
01-23 19:03:12.210: E/AndroidRuntime(30602):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
01-23 19:03:12.210: E/AndroidRuntime(30602):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
01-23 19:03:12.210: E/AndroidRuntime(30602):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-23 19:03:12.210: E/AndroidRuntime(30602): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class fragment
01-23 19:03:12.210: E/AndroidRuntime(30602):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:581)
01-23 19:03:12.210: E/AndroidRuntime(30602):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:386)
01-23 19:03:12.210: E/AndroidRuntime(30602):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
01-23 19:03:12.210: E/AndroidRuntime(30602):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
01-23 19:03:12.210: E/AndroidRuntime(30602):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:209)
01-23 19:03:12.210: E/AndroidRuntime(30602):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1657)
01-23 19:03:12.210: E/AndroidRuntime(30602):    at com.example.googlemapstest.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:12)
01-23 19:03:12.210: E/AndroidRuntime(30602):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
01-23 19:03:12.210: E/AndroidRuntime(30602):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
01-23 19:03:12.210: E/AndroidRuntime(30602):    ... 11 more
01-23 19:03:12.210: E/AndroidRuntime(30602): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.view.fragment in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.example.googlemapstest-1.apk]
01-23 19:03:12.210: E/AndroidRuntime(30602):    at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:240)
01-23 19:03:12.210: E/AndroidRuntime(30602):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:551)
01-23 19:03:12.210: E/AndroidRuntime(30602):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
01-23 19:03:12.210: E/AndroidRuntime(30602):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:471)
01-23 19:03:12.210: E/AndroidRuntime(30602):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:549)
01-23 19:03:12.210: E/AndroidRuntime(30602):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:66)
01-23 19:03:12.210: E/AndroidRuntime(30602):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:568)
01-23 19:03:12.210: E/AndroidRuntime(30602):    ... 19 more
```

After I get the errors, I online search for the answer, but I am still unable to run it. There are too many errors in the code, and new on android and esclipse, hope any expert can help on the coding, below is the coding:

**AndroidManinifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"package="com.example.googlemapstest" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
android:minSdkVersion="8"
android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="true"/>
            <permission android:name="com.example.googlemapstest.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"></permission>
            <uses-permission android:name="com.example.googlemapstest.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
            <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

            <application
                android:allowBackup="true"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
                <activity
                    android:name="com.example.googlemapstest.MainActivity"
                    android:label="@string/app_name" >
                    <intent-filter>
                        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                    </intent-filter>
                </activity>





       <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" 
 android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

       <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
          android:value="AIzaSyA6Ut59EIz-oi7RZrMiklR-LKyDgijnKvE" />
            </application>

        </manifest>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
    package com.example.googlemapstest;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
    import android.view.Menu;

    public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity  {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
// Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
return true;
        }

    }
```

**activity_main**

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
```

**Get SHA1**
[image]

**Get API key**
[image]

Added **google play services lib** in my project
[image]

I have been face these error for few days, and still not able to solve it. Hope any expert can help me to solve the problem. Thanks

After I add in the code below, and get almost the same error. Can anyone help me on this?

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
android:value="AIzaSyA6Ut59EIz-oi7RZrMiklR-LKyDgijnKvE" />
```

The errors show below:

```
01-24 09:26:22.023: D/dalvikvm(786): DexOpt: couldn't find field Landroid/content/res/Configuration;.smallestScreenWidthDp
01-24 09:26:22.031: W/dalvikvm(786): VFY: unable to resolve instance field 36
01-24 09:26:22.031: D/dalvikvm(786): VFY: replacing opcode 0x52 at 0x0012
01-24 09:26:22.031: D/dalvikvm(786): VFY: dead code 0x0014-0018 in Lcom/google/android/gms/common/GooglePlayServicesUtil;.b (Landroid/content/res/Resources;)Z
01-24 09:26:22.210: D/dalvikvm(786): GC_CONCURRENT freed 191K, 46% free 3071K/5639K, external 408K/517K, paused 3ms+5ms
01-24 09:26:22.421: D/dalvikvm(786): GC_CONCURRENT freed 129K, 42% free 3508K/6023K, external 408K/517K, paused 4ms+5ms
01-24 09:26:22.453: W/dalvikvm(786): Unable to resolve superclass of Lmaps/p/r; (643)
01-24 09:26:22.453: W/dalvikvm(786): Link of class 'Lmaps/p/r;' failed
01-24 09:26:22.453: W/dalvikvm(786): Unable to resolve superclass of Lmaps/ao/an; (6521)
01-24 09:26:22.453: W/dalvikvm(786): Link of class 'Lmaps/ao/an;' failed
01-24 09:26:22.453: W/dalvikvm(786): Unable to resolve superclass of Lmaps/ae/i; (5640)
01-24 09:26:22.453: W/dalvikvm(786): Link of class 'Lmaps/ae/i;' failed
01-24 09:26:22.453: E/dalvikvm(786): Could not find class 'maps.ae.i', referenced from method maps.af.al.a
01-24 09:26:22.453: W/dalvikvm(786): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 5490 (Lmaps/ae/i;) in Lmaps/af/al;
01-24 09:26:22.453: D/dalvikvm(786): VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x0091
01-24 09:26:22.484: D/dalvikvm(786): VFY: dead code 0x0093-00a0 in Lmaps/af/al;.a (Landroid/view/LayoutInflater;Lcom/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMapOptions;Z)Lmaps/af/al;
01-24 09:26:22.515: D/AndroidRuntime(786): Shutting down VM
01-24 09:26:22.515: W/dalvikvm(786): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40018578)
01-24 09:26:22.523: E/AndroidRuntime(786): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-24 09:26:22.523: E/AndroidRuntime(786): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.googlemapstest/com.example.googlemapstest.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class fragment
01-24 09:26:22.523: E/AndroidRuntime(786):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1651)
01-24 09:26:22.523: E/AndroidRuntime(786):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
01-24 09:26:22.523: E/AndroidRuntime(786):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
01-24 09:26:22.523: E/AndroidRuntime(786):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
01-24 09:26:22.523: E/AndroidRuntime(786):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-24 09:26:22.523: E/AndroidRuntime(786):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
01-24 09:26:22.523: E/AndroidRuntime(786):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
01-24 09:26:22.523: E/AndroidRuntime(786):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-24 09:26:22.523: E/AndroidRuntime(786):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
01-24 09:26:22.523: E/AndroidRuntime(786):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
01-24 09:26:22.523: E/AndroidRuntime(786):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
01-24 09:26:22.523: E/AndroidRuntime(786):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-24 09:26:22.523: E/AndroidRuntime(786): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class fragment
01-24 09:26:22.523: E/AndroidRuntime(786):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:587)
01-24 09:26:22.523: E/AndroidRuntime(786):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:386)
01-24 09:26:22.523: E/AndroidRuntime(786):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
01-24 09:26:22.523: E/AndroidRuntime(786):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
01-24 09:26:22.523: E/AndroidRuntime(786):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:209)
01-24 09:26:22.523: E/AndroidRuntime(786):  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1657)
01-24 09:26:22.523: E/AndroidRuntime(786):  at com.example.googlemapstest.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:12)
01-24 09:26:22.523: E/AndroidRuntime(786):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
01-24 09:26:22.523: E/AndroidRuntime(786):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
01-24 09:26:22.523: E/AndroidRuntime(786):  ... 11 more
01-24 09:26:22.523: E/AndroidRuntime(786): Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: The Maps API requires the additional following permissions to be set in the AndroidManifest.xml to ensure a correct behavior:
01-24 09:26:22.523: E/AndroidRuntime(786): <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
01-24 09:26:22.523: E/AndroidRuntime(786):  at maps.af.ch.a(Unknown Source)
01-24 09:26:22.523: E/AndroidRuntime(786):  at maps.af.ay.a(Unknown Source)
01-24 09:26:22.523: E/AndroidRuntime(786):  at maps.af.ay.a(Unknown Source)
01-24 09:26:22.523: E/AndroidRuntime(786):  at maps.af.al.a(Unknown Source)
01-24 09:26:22.523: E/AndroidRuntime(786):  at maps.af.bg.a(Unknown Source)
01-24 09:26:22.523: E/AndroidRuntime(786):  at maps.af.bf.a(Unknown Source)
01-24 09:26:22.523: E/AndroidRuntime(786):  at ebt.onTransact(SourceFile:107)
01-24 09:26:22.523: E/AndroidRuntime(786):  at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:279)
01-24 09:26:22.523: E/AndroidRuntime(786):  at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.IMapFragmentDelegate$a$a.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
01-24 09:26:22.523: E/AndroidRuntime(786):  at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$a.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
01-24 09:26:22.523: E/AndroidRuntime(786):  at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a$4.b(Unknown Source)
01-24 09:26:22.523: E/AndroidRuntime(786):  at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.a(Unknown Source)
01-24 09:26:22.523: E/AndroidRuntime(786):  at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
01-24 09:26:22.523: E/AndroidRuntime(786):  at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
01-24 09:26:22.523: E/AndroidRuntime(786):  at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1500)
01-24 09:26:22.523: E/AndroidRuntime(786):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:900)
01-24 09:26:22.523: E/AndroidRuntime(786):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1082)
01-24 09:26:22.523: E/AndroidRuntime(786):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1184)
01-24 09:26:22.523: E/AndroidRuntime(786):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:291)
01-24 09:26:22.523: E/AndroidRuntime(786):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:563)
01-24 09:26:22.523: E/AndroidRuntime(786):  ... 19 more
01-24 09:42:08.296: D/dalvikvm(989): DexOpt: couldn't find field Landroid/content/res/Configuration;.smallestScreenWidthDp
01-24 09:42:08.296: W/dalvikvm(989): VFY: unable to resolve instance field 36
01-24 09:42:08.296: D/dalvikvm(989): VFY: replacing opcode 0x52 at 0x0012
01-24 09:42:08.296: D/dalvikvm(989): VFY: dead code 0x0014-0018 in Lcom/google/android/gms/common/GooglePlayServicesUtil;.b (Landroid/content/res/Resources;)Z
01-24 09:42:08.437: D/dalvikvm(989): GC_CONCURRENT freed 196K, 46% free 3069K/5639K, external 408K/517K, paused 3ms+4ms
01-24 09:42:08.625: D/dalvikvm(989): GC_CONCURRENT freed 130K, 42% free 3508K/6023K, external 408K/517K, paused 3ms+5ms
01-24 09:42:08.656: W/dalvikvm(989): Unable to resolve superclass of Lmaps/p/r; (643)
01-24 09:42:08.656: W/dalvikvm(989): Link of class 'Lmaps/p/r;' failed
01-24 09:42:08.656: W/dalvikvm(989): Unable to resolve superclass of Lmaps/ao/an; (6521)
01-24 09:42:08.656: W/dalvikvm(989): Link of class 'Lmaps/ao/an;' failed
01-24 09:42:08.656: W/dalvikvm(989): Unable to resolve superclass of Lmaps/ae/i; (5640)
01-24 09:42:08.656: W/dalvikvm(989): Link of class 'Lmaps/ae/i;' failed
01-24 09:42:08.656: E/dalvikvm(989): Could not find class 'maps.ae.i', referenced from method maps.af.al.a
01-24 09:42:08.656: W/dalvikvm(989): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 5490 (Lmaps/ae/i;) in Lmaps/af/al;
01-24 09:42:08.656: D/dalvikvm(989): VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x0091
01-24 09:42:08.679: D/dalvikvm(989): VFY: dead code 0x0093-00a0 in Lmaps/af/al;.a (Landroid/view/LayoutInflater;Lcom/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMapOptions;Z)Lmaps/af/al;
01-24 09:42:08.710: D/AndroidRuntime(989): Shutting down VM
01-24 09:42:08.710: W/dalvikvm(989): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40018578)
01-24 09:42:08.718: E/AndroidRuntime(989): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-24 09:42:08.718: E/AndroidRuntime(989): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.googlemapstest/com.example.googlemapstest.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class fragment
01-24 09:42:08.718: E/AndroidRuntime(989):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1651)
01-24 09:42:08.718: E/AndroidRuntime(989):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
01-24 09:42:08.718: E/AndroidRuntime(989):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
01-24 09:42:08.718: E/AndroidRuntime(989):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
01-24 09:42:08.718: E/AndroidRuntime(989):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-24 09:42:08.718: E/AndroidRuntime(989):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
01-24 09:42:08.718: E/AndroidRuntime(989):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
01-24 09:42:08.718: E/AndroidRuntime(989):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-24 09:42:08.718: E/AndroidRuntime(989):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
01-24 09:42:08.718: E/AndroidRuntime(989):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
01-24 09:42:08.718: E/AndroidRuntime(989):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
01-24 09:42:08.718: E/AndroidRuntime(989):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-24 09:42:08.718: E/AndroidRuntime(989): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class fragment
01-24 09:42:08.718: E/AndroidRuntime(989):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:587)
01-24 09:42:08.718: E/AndroidRuntime(989):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:386)
01-24 09:42:08.718: E/AndroidRuntime(989):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
01-24 09:42:08.718: E/AndroidRuntime(989):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
01-24 09:42:08.718: E/AndroidRuntime(989):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:209)
01-24 09:42:08.718: E/AndroidRuntime(989):  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1657)
01-24 09:42:08.718: E/AndroidRuntime(989):  at com.example.googlemapstest.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:12)
01-24 09:42:08.718: E/AndroidRuntime(989):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
01-24 09:42:08.718: E/AndroidRuntime(989):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
01-24 09:42:08.718: E/AndroidRuntime(989):  ... 11 more
01-24 09:42:08.718: E/AndroidRuntime(989): Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: The Maps API requires the additional following permissions to be set in the AndroidManifest.xml to ensure a correct behavior:
01-24 09:42:08.718: E/AndroidRuntime(989): <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
01-24 09:42:08.718: E/AndroidRuntime(989):  at maps.af.ch.a(Unknown Source)
01-24 09:42:08.718: E/AndroidRuntime(989):  at maps.af.ay.a(Unknown Source)
01-24 09:42:08.718: E/AndroidRuntime(989):  at maps.af.ay.a(Unknown Source)
01-24 09:42:08.718: E/AndroidRuntime(989):  at maps.af.al.a(Unknown Source)
01-24 09:42:08.718: E/AndroidRuntime(989):  at maps.af.bg.a(Unknown Source)
01-24 09:42:08.718: E/AndroidRuntime(989):  at maps.af.bf.a(Unknown Source)
01-24 09:42:08.718: E/AndroidRuntime(989):  at ebt.onTransact(SourceFile:107)
01-24 09:42:08.718: E/AndroidRuntime(989):  at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:279)
01-24 09:42:08.718: E/AndroidRuntime(989):  at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.IMapFragmentDelegate$a$a.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
01-24 09:42:08.718: E/AndroidRuntime(989):  at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$a.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
01-24 09:42:08.718: E/AndroidRuntime(989):  at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a$4.b(Unknown Source)
01-24 09:42:08.718: E/AndroidRuntime(989):  at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.a(Unknown Source)
01-24 09:42:08.718: E/AndroidRuntime(989):  at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
01-24 09:42:08.718: E/AndroidRuntime(989):  at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
01-24 09:42:08.718: E/AndroidRuntime(989):  at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1500)
01-24 09:42:08.718: E/AndroidRuntime(989):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:900)
01-24 09:42:08.718: E/AndroidRuntime(989):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1082)
01-24 09:42:08.718: E/AndroidRuntime(989):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1184)
01-24 09:42:08.718: E/AndroidRuntime(989):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:291)
01-24 09:42:08.718: E/AndroidRuntime(989):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:563)
01-24 09:42:08.718: E/AndroidRuntime(989):  ... 19 more
```

I connect my Galaxy y to run my apps, will this cause the error happen?

After adding the code below

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Errors come again after I run it in my Galaxy Y, below is the error:

```
01-24 16:35:58.562: D/AndroidRuntime(9487): Shutting down VM
01-24 16:35:58.562: W/dalvikvm(9487): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40018578)
01-24 16:35:58.570: E/AndroidRuntime(9487): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-24 16:35:58.570: E/AndroidRuntime(9487): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{ca.sfu.cmpt277.arzozeus/ca.sfu.cmpt277.arzozeus.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16: Error inflating class fragment
01-24 16:35:58.570: E/AndroidRuntime(9487):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1651)
01-24 16:35:58.570: E/AndroidRuntime(9487):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
01-24 16:35:58.570: E/AndroidRuntime(9487):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
01-24 16:35:58.570: E/AndroidRuntime(9487):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
01-24 16:35:58.570: E/AndroidRuntime(9487):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-24 16:35:58.570: E/AndroidRuntime(9487):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
01-24 16:35:58.570: E/AndroidRuntime(9487):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
01-24 16:35:58.570: E/AndroidRuntime(9487):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-24 16:35:58.570: E/AndroidRuntime(9487):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
01-24 16:35:58.570: E/AndroidRuntime(9487):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
01-24 16:35:58.570: E/AndroidRuntime(9487):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
01-24 16:35:58.570: E/AndroidRuntime(9487):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-24 16:35:58.570: E/AndroidRuntime(9487): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16: Error inflating class fragment
01-24 16:35:58.570: E/AndroidRuntime(9487):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:581)
01-24 16:35:58.570: E/AndroidRuntime(9487):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:623)
01-24 16:35:58.570: E/AndroidRuntime(9487):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:408)
01-24 16:35:58.570: E/AndroidRuntime(9487):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
01-24 16:35:58.570: E/AndroidRuntime(9487):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
01-24 16:35:58.570: E/AndroidRuntime(9487):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:209)
01-24 16:35:58.570: E/AndroidRuntime(9487):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1657)
01-24 16:35:58.570: E/AndroidRuntime(9487):     at ca.sfu.cmpt277.arzozeus.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:12)
01-24 16:35:58.570: E/AndroidRuntime(9487):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
01-24 16:35:58.570: E/AndroidRuntime(9487):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
01-24 16:35:58.570: E/AndroidRuntime(9487):     ... 11 more
01-24 16:35:58.570: E/AndroidRuntime(9487): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.view.fragment in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/ca.sfu.cmpt277.arzozeus-2.apk]
01-24 16:35:58.570: E/AndroidRuntime(9487):     at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:240)
01-24 16:35:58.570: E/AndroidRuntime(9487):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:551)
01-24 16:35:58.570: E/AndroidRuntime(9487):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
01-24 16:35:58.570: E/AndroidRuntime(9487):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:471)
01-24 16:35:58.570: E/AndroidRuntime(9487):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:549)
01-24 16:35:58.570: E/AndroidRuntime(9487):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:66)
01-24 16:35:58.570: E/AndroidRuntime(9487):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:568)
01-24 16:35:58.570: E/AndroidRuntime(9487):     ... 20 more
```

Comment: Add this to manifest- <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

Answer (score 1):

see this answer:

Link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18511945

and add the following permission in manifiest:

```
<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

Comment: I add in the code you provide in my project and get error as well. I also go to the link you provide, what its mean "Manually uninstall the App from device and restart the device"? I also recreate my key again, but still can't fixed the error. Please help, thanks.

Comment: @Arzozeus  paste your error brother and update your google play service from sdk and again import google play services in your ecilips from your sdk

Comment: I paste my error at the last part, currently I have paste three error log in my post. After I add the code, and also delete and install again my google play service but still hit error. Please help, thanks.

Comment: @Arzozeus In Project build target select google api target 4.4.2

Answer (score 1):

Under Application Element in manifest add this for Eclipse :

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" 
 android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
          android:value="Your KEY" />
```

If you are using Android Studio with gradle0.7+ then add this line:

```
<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="Your Key" />
```

Comment: After I have add the code in my project and I still get errors, can you help me, what's wrong about my code?Thanks

Comment: @Arzozeous please  re-post your logcat with new errors and manifest file. Make sure to clean your project by ./gradlew clean.

Comment: @Arzozeus  Please add this line in your manifest <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

Comment: @Arzozeus.. this error is very clear from logcat Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: The Maps API requires the additional following permissions to be set in the AndroidManifest.xml to ensure a correct behavior:
01-24 09:42:08.718: E/AndroidRuntime(989): <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

Comment: After I add the coding, and rerun my code, but still hit errors. I run it in my Galaxy Y, is Galaxy Y support google play service? Thanks

Comment: API key is tightly coupled with package name. Please regenerate the SHA1 key with same package name .

Comment: Check this link how to generate key http://www.androidhive.info/2013/08/android-working-with-google-maps-v2/